# Plugins giving error after Wordpress migration

Tags: wordpress, plugins, database-migration

I just moved a Wordpress site from one URL to the other. The website itself seems to work fine except when I try to login via /wp-admin I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 100663296 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 122880 bytes) in
>   /home/deb52080/domains/r2blog.nl/public_html/wp-admin/includes/media.php
>   on line 2840

I allready run some tests by disabling a plugin and that seemed to have solved the problem (except that I need this plugin and I use it all the time). But the moment I clicked one a function from any other plugin I get the same error.

Hope somebody is able to help me. These are plugins that I use regularly (Smart Slider 3 and Fusion Builder from the Avada thema) and they never give any problem.

Comment: Your php probably consumes more RAM than allowed. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/increasing-the-wordpress-memory-limit/

Answer (score 1):

Did you happen to move your new site to `Siteground` as the host? There is a known conflict between the `Avada` theme and `Siteground`.

The suggested workaround is to simply go to the `Avada` menu in the admin panel, choose Register and then remove your API key and save it as blank. Be warned that doing so will eliminate the automatic theme updates `Avada` provides.

If that doesn't work this thread from the `Avada` community site provides some solutions on how to increase your memory limit in the wp-config file:
https://theme-fusion.com/forums/topic/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-805306368-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate/

Comment: Good first answer buddy. Welcome to StackOverflow!